# Dockerfile is building from Centos:7 - is there a way to instruct npm to be installed?

Tags: docker, npm, dockerfile, centos7, docker-container

I have to make use of an existing Dockerfile, which generates a docker image from Centos 7.  (FROM centos:7  , is the first line in the Dockerfile.)

I need to be able to run 'npm install' and 'npm run' commands within the containers that will be running this image, but npm is not installed.  The ways I find online how to install npm on Centos 7 also do not work, as they rely on things such as apt-get which also is not installed in the container.  Not having sudo also seems to be an issue.

**Is there a way to configure the actual Dockerfile, to build the image, and have npm installed on that image being built?  If not - how can I go about installing npm within the docker containers that will run this Centos7 image?**

ANSWER:  I added this to the Dockerfile:

```
RUN yum install -y epel-release
RUN yum install -y npm nodejs
```

Comment: Please don't answer by editing the question. Either accept one of the answers given or post your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CentOS and (and other EL distributions) do not use `apt`, they use `yum` (or `dnf`). Unfortunately, `npm` isn't packaged in CentOS' normal repos, os you'd have to install the EPEL repo fist:

Simple add a `yum` call in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN yum install -y http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

RUN yum install -y npm
```

Comment: Unfortunately this returns a non-0 code with : "No package npm available.
Error: Nothing to do"

Comment: Hey I found what it was, I needed to give one extra:

RUN yum install -y epel-release
RUN yum install -y npm nodejs

Comment: @ffConundrums forgot about EPEL, mea culpa. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks!  Yes this exact edit in my Dockerfile allowed it to work:

`RUN yum install -y epel-release`

`RUN yum install -y npm nodejs`